# "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
totalTime = 0
def start(s):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        while True:
                if time.perf_counter()-start > s:
                        return True


def conversion(Time):
        Time = Time.split(":")
        time1 = int(Time[0])*60
        return time1+int(Time[1])

def main():
        start = time.perf_counter()

        global totalTime
        Time = input("Enter Time [00:00]: ")
        end = time.perf_counter()

        conTime = conversion(Time)
        totalTime += conTime
        totalTime += round(end-start)

        start(conTime)

        print(f"{Time} is Completed!!")

while True:
        main()
```

When `time.perf_counter()` isn't there it works perfectly fine. I cant seem to find out why `conTime` is being transformed into a `float` instead of an `int`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/timer.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/timer.py", line 27, in main
    start(int(conTime))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: You are using `start` as the name of both a function and a variable.  Rename one of those things.

Comment: @jasonharper same issue

Comment: As an aside... Are you sure you want that CPU-hogging code in your *start()* function?

Comment: Didn't you post a similar question yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a function with the name `start` that you want to call but you are also declaring a variable with the name `start` in the main function.

You need to rename the function or the variable to make it work, here is a working example of your code with a different function name:

```
import time

totalTime = 0


def start_perf(s):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if time.perf_counter() - start > s:
            return True


def conversion(Time):
    Time = Time.split(":")
    time1 = int(Time[0]) * 60
    return time1 + int(Time[1])


def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()

    global totalTime
    Time = input("Enter Time [00:00]: ")
    end = time.perf_counter()

    conTime = conversion(Time)
    totalTime += conTime
    totalTime += round(end - start)

    start_perf(conTime)

    print(f"{Time} is Completed!!")


while True:
    main()
```